# Using one variable as a reference to another in swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I keep all of my users data in a `User` object and access it when I need it, as demonstrated in the example below on line 1. The inconvenience I encounter when using this method of data storing is when I need to edit these objects. Below, I have a `Time` object which belongs to the current user. Ideally, I would set the current user's times to a variable to make it more manageable, and then edit the times using that variable. The problem is, the `time` variable doesn't refer to the `User.current().times[0]` variable. Is there a way of using a variable essentially as a shortcut?

```
let time = User.current().times[0]
time.name = titleLabel.text
time.start = start
time.end = end
time.save()
```

`User.current().times` is of type `[Time]` which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

---

The declaration of the `User` class as requested with the `current()` function.

```
var this_user: User?

class User: NSObject {
    var times = [Time]()
    class func current() -> User {
        if this_user == nil {
            this_user = User()
        }
        return this_user!
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would describe your object in more detail. Show the declaration for the User class, show the implementation of its `current` method, and show what `times` consists of - is it an array, and what sort of objects does it contain?

Comment: But please show the info I asked for. Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Also for the one who downvoted this question and voted to close it, could you please enlighten me as to why this programming question about a specific problem I am encountering is 'off topic'?

Comment: You do realize that this way of creating a singleton is insecure? Any code can come along and set `this_user` to something else. Not a big deal, but using a global this way is not the best pattern.

Comment: @matt how would you do it?

Comment: Do a search on "swift singleton", the standard pattern is discussed in detail here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, I tested the code you provided, and it works perfectly. So there must be something wrong with your testing. See my new answer.

Comment: Unless `Time` is declared as a `struct` (which would be impossible if it inherits from `NSObject`), your works. Please make sure that this specific example fails.

Answer (score 1):

> Classes Are Reference Types
>
> Unlike value types, reference types are not copied when they are assigned to a variable or constant, or when they are passed to a function. Rather than a copy, a reference to the same existing instance is used instead.

Just check `User().current().times[0]`. Is it a class or only a value? If you make an user object and holds that reference then you can get those.

[For more Info see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html).

Comment: `User.current().times[0]` is an object of type `Time` which is an `NSObject` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work. The fault is in your testing procedure.

To prove this, I set up mock versions of your classes at the top level of a file, like this:

```
var this_user : User?

class Time : NSObject {
    var start : String!
}

class User: NSObject {
    var times = [Time]()
    class func current() -> User {
        if this_user == nil {
            this_user = User()
        }
        return this_user!
    }
}
```

Then, elsewhere, I ran this code:

```
    let cur = User.current()
    cur.times.append(Time()) // to give us a first Time in times

    let time = User.current().times[0]
    time.start = "Testing" // so let's see if we can write into it!

    println(User.current().times[0].start) // Testing
```

This proves that when I set `time.start` it *does* reflect back into the Time that is in the `times` array of the current User. Therefore, I conclude that there is something wrong with the way you are testing your code. (Either that, or your description of your objects is inaccurate.)